# MySQL Search Query Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am trying to build a MySQL FULL TEXT based search engine, i am not getting any results for search made.
I am working on MySQL Version is 5.5.24 which support FULL TEXT for Innodb. so i have kept database type to Innodb for speed purpose, also my collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

i have set field "title" type to TEXT and altered table "test_table" like.

```
ALTER TABLE `test_table` ADD FULLTEXT (`title`)
```

I am writing query like this but no result were displayed.

```
    require_once('../global/includes/connect.php');
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM test_table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('%keyword%')");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){
echo $row['title'];
echo"</br>";
}
```

for query like this

```
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM test_table ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){
echo $row['title'];
echo"</br>";
```

results are displayed.

I tried changing database to MyISAM, but same problem.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, modified query

```
$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM test_table WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ")or die (mysql_error());
```

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
require_once('../global/includes/connect.php');
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT MATCH(title) FROM test_table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('security')") OR die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)){
echo $row['title'];
echo"</br>";
}
```

Comment: tried but got error  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Could you give the mysql_error? (mysql_query(your_sql) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: Fatal error: SQL in D:\wamp\www\Software Site\test.php on line 4

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test_table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('security')' at line 1

Comment: It seems that the query is incorrect. You can try editing it in a mysql administrator and test it until you find the correct one as I don't see what the problem could be.

Comment: yes it was query error, got it right, thanks for your help to point out the query mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `$` before `keyword`.

```
$sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM test_table 
                         WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('%$keyword%')"); 
                                                       ^
```

Also read [`this`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html).